# How to create database schema with shared primary foreign key?

Tags: database, postgresql

My goal is to have a subtable whose primary key and foreign key both are the same column, and reference to an ID of the main table.

```
CREATE TABLE main_table(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    //some fields
)

CREATE TABLE test(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARAY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT test_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_id)
        REFERENCES main_table (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

But this will create a table mapping with two columns: id[PK] and test_fk as foreign key column. How can I combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how the `foreign key` clause works. You list the names of *existing* columns in there. And listing the column names will create any new column. Any FK column must have already be defined in the "columns part" of the  `create table` statement.

So your statement wouldn't work at all because the table `test` does not have a column named `fk_id`. You need to supply the name of the already defined column `id` there:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARAY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT test_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) --- <<< this was wrong
        REFERENCES main_table (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```